# Decode PHP called with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, decoding

In a `.php` file I have some PHP code which is encoded with [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), and it decodes fine with some `base64_decode` code that is in a `.js` file.

However in the same `.php` file using JavaScript, I have been calling the same PHP code. Even though this is still being encoded, it does not appear to be decoded from the same `.js` file.

```
<?php
    $items_folder="http://domain/items/";
    $items_folder_enc=base64_encode($items_folder);
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var itemsnew=<?php echo json_encode($items_folder_enc); ?>;
```

What can I change so that the `<?php echo json_encode($items_folder_enc); ?>;` is decoded like its PHP counterpart?

Comment: $items_folder_enc is encoding the string $items_folder. json_encode will just return a string (I think). Edit this question to explain more fully what you are trying to do

Comment: which `;`, the one that terminates the `var itemsnew...` line? That's not part of the base64-encoded text. Ditto for the `$items_folder = ` line. the `;` is NOT part of the string, it's a statement terminator in both of the languages.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. If you don't need `$items_folder` base64-encoded, why even have the call to `base64_encode`?

Comment: What php counterpart is being decoded? I'm having a hard time understanding.

Comment: I have a player which plays items. One player uses regular php code and the other javascript. Regular php version encodes item folder and js file decodes this information through player. Trying to do same for javascript player. So yes I do want base64_encode.

Comment: `var itemsnew=<?php echo json_encode($items_folder_enc); ?>;` Are you trying to json encode or base64 decode this variable? It's just unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Which player are you showing us through your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decode server-side and send `$items_folder` to client as plain text then:

```
var itemsnew = "<?php echo base64_decode($items_folder_enc); ?>";
```

If you want to decode client-side and send `$items_folder` to client in an "encoded" manner then:

```
var itemsnew = atob("<?php echo $items_folder_enc; ?>");
```

In the later case, you might want to check for [atob support](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/client-object-property-method/window-btoa.php) and create a base64 decoding user function if browser doesn't support it.

Comment: +1 For addressing `atob` compatibility issues! Here is another link for atob compatibility [Window.atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.atob#Browser_compatibility)